# three dimensional subspace question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

If a vector is in $\mathbb{R}^5$, does this mean that the projection of this vector onto $S$ is in $\mathbb{R}^3$, where $S$ is some 3-dim subspace of $\mathbb{R}^5$?

Comment: No. It still lives in $\mathbb{R}^5$. It's still described by $5$ coordinates (even if two are irrelevant).

Comment: The best you can say is what you have said. $S$ is not $\mathbb R^3$, only isomorphic to it. The analogy is that every line in the plane isn't $\mathbb R$, just isomorphic to it.

Comment: Adding to the comment of @CameronWilliams, note that the subspace can cut through all coordinates. It needn't be something like $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times \{0\} \times \{0\}$. And even this last space isn't $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$, just isomorphic to it.